# Laravel 5 - configuring .env and .db file

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

I just started learning php/laravel. I've setup Laravel+xampp+VB(vagrant) for my learning purposes. Everything worked fine till I tried to do

```
php artisan migrate
```

I got:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'homestead' (SQL: select * from informatio
n_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'homestead'
```

I'm pretty sure my file configuration doesn't add up (I tried different approaches to fix this error before posting)...

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

.dbphp

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I've no clue what I'm doing, so I sincerely hope that someone will lead me to right direction. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tsr3NgoExfo

I did this to try and fix my problem (didnt help): http://tutsnare.com/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-laravel-5/

Comment: so, you need to write your database info in .env file I can't understand, did you do this?

Comment: @Danielius I created table in bash console, but I didn't change any configuration (env/db files), because I thought it's settup by default(?). Should my newly created table be in localhost/phpmyadmin?

Comment: nah, you just need to open your env file and set info here `DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=''`

Comment: @Danielius Well, as u can see - I've that configuration, but I get errors (top).

Comment: have you set that "homestead" with your own data? because you get error where it is written, that you want to connect to database "homestead" - I believe there should be different name..with user which name is "homestead"  (well, i think you use other user f.e. root if in local server)

Comment: @Danielius Where can I check my own data (username settings ect.?)

Comment: if it's default, your user should be 'root' and no password. You should know your created database name xD

Comment: have you found everything?

Comment: @Danielius I make model and dbseeder file. Is model = db name?

Comment: Nope, go to your `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and create a database here (if you need to login - username: root, no password. and then use that database name in your env. I really recommend you to first learn how pure php+MySQL works and only then think about something like laravel... You need to learn much first, OOP included.

Comment: @Danielius Okay. after I create db there, how can I add a single table to it (I guess I've to do that through bash console?) and then how to migrate? Can u give me small step by step as answer? thanks

Comment: when you migrate your migrations it will add a database table.open your `database/migrations` and there you will find all migrations. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns here you can find, what types of columns you can write in your migration and also https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#migration-structure thats how basic migration looks like. to migrate just write `php artisan migrate` as you already tried

Comment: @Danielius Watched few videos and everything is working now! I had to configure my .env correctly. Thanks!

Comment: no problem :) Good luck